Problems with chemfig in LaTeXiT
I'm trying to point out the angle formed between the Cl2Be atoms, but no matter how hard I try, the angle appears on the side of the structure. Do you know how I can fix this?

\chemfig{%
@{a}\charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{Cl}-@{b}Be-@{c}\charge{90=\:,0=\:,270=\:}{Cl}%
}
\arclabel{0.5cm}{c}{b}{a}{\scriptsize$\alpha$}

I'm using LaTeXiT and this is my template:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bm,mathrsfs,cancel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{elements,chemmacros}
\newcommand\namebond[5][-1pt]{\chemmove{\path(#2)--(#3)node[midway,#4,yshift=#1,black!60]{#5};}}
\newcommand\arcbetweennodes[3]{%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
    \let#3\pgfmathresult}

\newcommand\arclabel[6][red,stealth-stealth,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt]{%
    \chemmove{%
        \arcbetweennodes{#4}{#3}\anglestart
        \arcbetweennodes{#4}{#5}\angleend
        \ifdim\anglestart pt>\angleend pt \pgfmathsetmacro\anglestart{\anglestart-360}\fi
        \draw[#1]([shift=(\anglestart:#2)]#4)arc[start angle=\anglestart,end angle=\angleend,radius=#2];%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\anglestart{(\anglestart+\angleend)/2}%
        \node[shift=(\anglestart:#2+1pt)#4,anchor=\anglestart+180,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at(#4){#6};%
    }%
}

Thanks!

I compiled your code in TeXLive and it worked fine. I don't have LaTeXiT to test it, sorry.

@CrocoDuck I have compiled it in Overleaf and MiKTeX and it works fine, but in LaTeXiT it appears like that. I don't know what could be happening.

You could create a file for this single image using the "standalone" class (\documentclass{standalone}) in Overleaf to create a PDF file of this image, and insert the image into your article.
